# unable to create remote directory named as a date

Tags: shell, unix

What am I doing wrong with this shell script? I want to create a directory remotely, naming it with a date stamp.

```
DIRDATE=`date '+%Y%m%d'`
BASE=/home/foo
KEYFILE=$BASE/.ssh/host_rsa
TESTDMPDIR=/home/files
TGTDIR=$BASE/$DIRDATE
export BASE KEYFILE TESTDMPDIR TGTDIR 

/usr/bin/ssh -p 1234 -i $KEYFILE foo@$1 'mkdir $TGTDIR'
/usr/bin/scp -P 1234 -i $KEYFILE $TESTDMPDIR/*.gz foo@$1:$TGTDIR
```

Output: (it says the directory exists, but it doesn't)

```
mkdir: cannot create directory `$TGTDIR': File exists
foobar.dat.gz                                                   100%    0     0.0KB/s   00:00
```

Server: (notice, that its creating a file and not a directory)

```
-rw-r--r--  1 foo users 0 Mar  9 22:13 20110309
```

Comment: There's no reason to `export` any of those variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem are the single quotation marks "'" around "mkdir $TGTDIR".
The variable is not expanded if it is enclosed in single quotes.
Therefore you should try

```
/usr/bin/ssh -p 1234 -i $KEYFILE foo@$1 "mkdir $TGTDIR"
```

Answer (score 0):

mkdir: cannot create directory `$TGTDIR': File exists ,this means file  already exists,if you execute same script multiple time it tries to create file with same datename,once file created it won't overwrite it throws File Exists ,

USe Condition there

```
DIRDATE=`date '+%Y%m%d'`
BASE=/home/foo
KEYFILE=$BASE/.ssh/host_rsa
TESTDMPDIR=/home/files
TGTDIR=$BASE/$DIRDATE

     if [ ! -f   $TGTDIR ]
        then 
            create
        fi
```

or 
if you want to create multiple times then add
 hour , minutes and sec to `DIRDATE=`date '+%Y%m%d-%H-%M-%S'

Comment: The directory isn't there. I removed it before I ran it. Also, the shell i'm using is very limited. So, I can't do a test -d remotely. I can only do a mkdir.